# ReactJS Foundation modal popup for delete confirmation & Datatable for Reactjs and foundation with sorting/paging support

Tags: reactjs, zurb-foundation

Can anyone suggest me good modal popup for reactjs and ? I want it for delete confirmation. I tried react-foundation-apps 's modal, but due to less documentation i am unable to use it for delete functionality in tabular data.

```
var React = require('react');

var EmployeeList = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var employees = this.props.employees.map(function(e, i){
            return (
                <tr key={i}>
                    <td>{e.employeeName}</td>
                    <td><a title="edit" href="#"><i  className="fi-pencil"></i></a></td>
                    <td>
                        <a title="delete" href="#"><i className="fi-trash"></i></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                )
        }, this);

        return (
            <div>
                <table id="users">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Employee</th>
                            <th>Edit</th>
                            <th>Delete</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {employees}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = EmployeeList;
```

Plus

Suggest me good datatable/datagrid for reactjs with foundation.

Answer (score 0):

A model is a simple pattern you can build yourself. The main attributes are absolute positioning, show/hide and high zIndex. Here is an example.

```js
import React from 'react';

import Actions from '../../flux/Actions';
import TreeViewB from './../common/jTreeViewB';

let JumpListSty = {
  backgroundColor: '#e1ded5',
  left: '20px',
  maxHeight: '80%',
  overflow: 'auto',
  position: 'absolute',
  top: '30px',
  width: '350px',
  zIndex: '100'
};

export default class JumpList extends React.Component {
  clickHandler = (node) => { Actions.selectJumpNode(node); Actions.appActions('jump'); }
  render() {
    if (this.props.hide) return null;
    let options = {
      icon: {sun: 1, leaf: 2, snow: 3},
      typeName: ['node', 'nodeLevel']
    };
    let isMobile = (this.props.appState.deviceType == 'mobile');
    return (
      <div id='JumpListSty' style={JumpListSty}>
        <TreeViewB data={this.props.data} options={options} titleClick={this.clickHandler} mobile={isMobile} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```js
<JumpList data={jumpData} appState={this.props.appState} hide={hideJump} />
```

Answer (score 0):

A datagrid is a simple pattern also. It is a arrangement of columns contained in a map of rows. You can use an html table or not.

```js
function dataMap(item, index) {
  return (
    <tr key={item._id + index}>
      <td ></td>
      <td style={columnSty}>{item.userinclude}</td>
      <td style={columnSty}>{item.domaininclude}</td>
      <td style={columnSty}>{item.userexclude}</td>
      <td style={columnSty}>{item.domainexclude}</td>
      <td style={columnSty}>{item.userskip}</td>
      <td style={columnSty}>{item.domainskip}</td>
      <td style={lastColumnSty}>{item._id}</td>
    </tr>
  )
}

export default class AggregateList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let list = this.props.data.map(dataMap);
    return (
      <div id='AggregateListSty' style={AggregateListSty}>
        <table >
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th ></th>
              <th style={columnHeaderSty}></th>
              <th style={columnHeaderSty}>Protested</th>
              <th style={columnHeaderSty}></th>
              <th style={columnHeaderSty}>Excluded</th>
              <th style={columnHeaderSty}></th>
              <th style={columnHeaderSty}>Skipped</th>
              <th style={lastColumnSty}></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th ></th>
              <th style={columnHeaderSty}>User</th>
              <th style={columnHeaderSty}>All</th>
              <th style={columnHeaderSty}>User</th>
              <th style={columnHeaderSty}>All</th>
              <th style={columnHeaderSty}>User</th>
              <th style={columnHeaderSty}>All</th>
              <th style={lastColumnSty}></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {list}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```